# Understanding swift typealias

Tags: swift, photosframework

As part of Photos framework, there is an options to download photos from iCloud(if needed). The problem is that i don't understand how to use it.

The docs says :

```
var progressHandler: PHAssetImageProgressHandler?
```

Where `PHAssetImageProgressHandler` is

**The signature for a block that Photos calls while downloading asset data from iCloud. Used by the progressHandler property.**

```
typealias PHAssetImageProgressHandler = (Double, NSError?, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>, [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Void
```

But i have no idea how to integrate it, any suggestions folks?

**UPDATE**

the request i'm using

```
      var options: PHImageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
      options.networkAccessAllowed = true
        options.progressHandler = PHAssetImageProgressHandler {

        }
```

Comment: It's a closure, a callback.  Can you give an example of which Photos framework call you're trying to use the callback with?

Comment: @JAL , Updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's used as a closure in the class `PHImageRequestOptions` which is passed for example to `requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:` of `PHImageManager`.

The syntax looks like

```
let finalRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
finalRequestOptions.progressHandler = { (progress, error, stop, info) in
  // do something with the returned parameters
}
```

The documentation says:

> If you request an image whose data is not on the local device, and you
>   have enabled downloading with the networkAccessAllowed property,
>   Photos calls your block periodically to report progress and to allow
>   you to cancel the download.

There is a good description of `PHImageManager` on [nshipster](http://nshipster.com/phimagemanager/)

Comment: Thank you! The reference to nshipster is priceless!

Answer (score 2):

It means that whenever you see `PHAssetImageProgressHandler`, you should actually read the following :

`(Double, NSError?, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>, [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Void`

which is a closure that takes the tuple `(Double, NSError?, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>, [NSObject : AnyObject]?)` as a parameter and that returns `Void`

Edit :

This also means that whenever you want to declare a `PHAssetImageProgressHandler`, you should declare it that way :

```
 let handler : PHAssetImageProgressHandler = { (progress, error, stop, info) in 
   // your code
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer aimak! :)